# How to plot profiles in R with ggplot2

Tags: r

I have a large data set with protein IDs and corresponding abundance profiles across a number of gel fractions. I want to plot these profiles of abundances across the fractions.

The data looks like this

```
IDs<- c("prot1", "prot2", "prot3", "prot4")
fraction1 <- c(3,4,2,4)
fraction2<- c(1,2,4,1)
fraction3<- c(6,4,6,2)
plotdata<-data.frame(IDs, fraction1, fraction2, fraction3)

> plotdata
    IDs  fraction1  fraction2  fraction3
1 prot1          3          1          6
2 prot2          4          2          4
3 prot3          2          4          6
4 prot4          4          1          2
```

I want it to look like this: [image: a plot made in excel of protein abundances]

Every protein has a profile. Every fraction has a corresponding abundance value per protein. I want to have multiple proteins per plot.

I tried figuring out ggplot2 using the cheat sheet and failed. I don't know what the input df should look like and what method I should use to get these profiles.

I would use excel, but a bug draws the wrong profile of my data depending on order of data, so I can't trust it to do what I want.

Comment: Data that you provided doesn't have get fraction information

Comment: edited for clarification.

Comment: Are the different colors in excel the different proteins, or are the different proteins on the x-axis? 
I might be easier if you describe more clearly how the plot is created or add the output of `dput(yourdata)` to your post. 
See also here: [how to make a reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, you'll have to reorganize your data.frame for ggplot2. You can do it one step with `reshape2::melt`. Here you can change the 'variable' and 'value' names.

```
library(reshape2)
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)
data2 <- melt(plotdata, id.vars = "IDs")
```

Then, we'll group the data by protein:

```
data2 <- group_by(data2, IDs)
```

Finally, you can plot it quite simply:

```
ggplot(data2) +
    geom_line(aes(variable, value, group = IDs,
                  color = IDs))
```

Comment: thank you so much, I did not find this anywhere. saved my day.

Comment: I used your example on my real data and right now the y axis scale is messed up, it doesn't go from 0 to max but instead just orders every occuring value equidistant from the min_value to the max_value. What is the command to make it a continuous scale? Example: https://imgur.com/a/B4nEu

Comment: I mean scale_y_continuous

Comment: I also had the problem that my numeric values were stored as characters, which leads to discrete display instead of numeric display. Using transform(df, values = as.numeric(values)) I could change my numbers to be interpreted as numeric which resolved the scale issue. My plot is really beautiful now, thanks again for the help.